# Total amount is ok when i enter one record in both tables if i insert 2nd record in 2nd talble than total amount will double

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Dear all friends i am new in Codeigniter framework i want total amount by selecting two table data, the problem is that when i enter data in 2nd table than total will double.

```
function total_amount($booking_no = NULL)
{
    $data  = array('forwarding_cargo_booking_details.*',
                   'other_charges.client_amount');


    $this->db->select($data);
    $this->db->where('forwarding_cargo_booking_details.booking_no',$booking_no);
    $this->db->join('other_charges','forwarding_cargo_booking_details.booking_no = other_charges.booking_no','left');
    $this->db->select('sum((`bk_m3`*`o_freight_client`)*(`selling_rate`)+`pod_client`+`thc_client`+`caf_client`+`baf_client`+`haulage_client`+`war_risk_client`+`warehouse_client`+`thc_dest_client`+`pp_surcharge_client`+`doc_charges_client`+`client_amount`) as salam', FAlSE);
    $query = $this->db->get('forwarding_cargo_booking_details');            
    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to this. Here use derieved query and test if it works ok

```
function total_amount($booking_no = NULL)
{
    $sql_query  =   "SELECT
                        forwarding_cargo_booking_details.*,
                        other_charges.client_amount,
                        sum((`bk_m3`*`o_freight_client`)*(`selling_rate`)+`pod_client`+`thc_client`+`caf_client`+`baf_client`+`haulage_client`+`war_risk_client`+`warehouse_client`+`thc_dest_client`+`pp_surcharge_client`+`doc_charges_client`+`client_amount`) as amount
                    FROM forwarding_cargo_booking_details 
                    LEFT JOIN (SELECT booking_no , sum(client_amount) FROM other_charges group by booking_no) as other_charges ON forwarding_cargo_booking_details.booking_no = other_charges.booking_no
                    ";
    $query = $this->db->query();   

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to print the query, and check the query.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

i think you forget to use "Group By" in your query